# Hydrophobic elution times in ionic exchange columns

Tags: lab-techniques, chromatography

What would the order of elution be of say Gly, Val, Leu?

My argument is that hydrophobic residues will try and get away from the resin and the more hydrophobic the residue is the faster it will elute. This seems to run contrary to the steric argument however, where larger residues would take longer to elute. Which argument is right?

Comment: What kind of column are you using?

Comment: Does it matter? Since all the pI's are the same?